# Spark Streaming - textFileStreaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I would like read files from a directory using textFileStream. My instruction is:

```
JavaDStream<String> lines = ssc.textFileStream("file:///C:/cdr/").cache();
```

By when I add files that directory, my application cant read the file.

My code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaNetworkWordCount").setMaster("local[2]");
    JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(1));

    JavaDStream<String> lines = ssc.textFileStream("file:///C:/cdr/").cache();

    JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(x -> Arrays.asList(SPACE.split(x)).iterator());
    JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordCounts = words.mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<>(s, 1))
            .reduceByKey((i1, i2) -> i1 + i2);

    wordCounts.print();
    ssc.start();
    ssc.awaitTermination();
}
```

thanks for help me.

Comment: How do you know that _"when I add files that directory, my application cant read the file."_? What's that thing that gives you this _impression_?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski thank you for feedback. I fix my url "file://C:/cdr/" instead of "file:///C:/cdr/". This way when I put inside directory the file, then it runs. But you can tell me if it's normal doesnt read the first file that you put on directory or if I put another file with the same content it hasnt process too ?